# Why aren't the Nomus' brains attacked?

Tags: my-hero-academia

In My Hero Academia, the Nomu are incredibly strong creatures that possess multiple quirks. Even a single one of them proves to be a big threat. Nomu or not, the brain of any creature is very weak and one could die if it doesn't have any kind of protection (usually skull). The Nomu seem to have brains without any kind of protection. They are clearly exposed and visible to everyone around. Considering the fact that the Nomu are strong creatures and the law doesn't restrict to kill them (since Endeavor killed many of them at the Hosu incident and also the high-end one), why don't pro heroes attack the Nomus' brains? (I know it looks gross and all the stuff, but that doesn't change the fact).

Comment: Maybe they did try to attack but the Nomus defended themselves.

Comment: Endeavor incinerates the head of one.  I think it mostly boils down to some combination of three things (1) it's a show for teenagers or thereabouts, you can't show too much brutality; (2) most of the heroes make an effort to maintain a good public image that's palatable to adults and children alike (for some that seems to be their only goal), and bloody, lethal attacks kind of work against that.  Endeavor is one of the few who doesn't care that much; and (3) heroes are a regulated part of the justice system, and pre-trial killings threaten justice and society's tenuous acceptance of quirks.

Comment: But that's just my speculation.  I don't know if there's anything specific we can cite from the manga or anime that would favor one or more (or any) of them.

Comment: Sujal Motagi There are heroes who specialise in accuracy like a teacher in UA. They can shoot from a distance when he Nomu is off guard and if it hits their brain they are done for, right?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, not all Nomu have their so-called brains exposed. Their description hints that they are "mindless" soldiers that  need specific orders to function. Only the High-Tier ones have the capability to think for themselves. On the same note, you could wonder why they don't target the eyes of Nomu.

On one hand, giving that they all have muscle augmentation and others physical quirks, one could reason that the visible "brain" tissue is just a protective layer for the brain itself. On the other hand, it could be that the Nomu are aware of this "flaw" and one can't easily target that area, being direct attack or range attack. Also, most fights in manga/anime don't revolve around the characters targeting the weak spots of the body, meaning that even in BnHA, the Heroes don't go for the head when fighting any other villain to give them a concussion or something like that, the fights are a display of abilities and power.

And finally, my opinion is that it's just a design trait that Horikoshi - the author - liked and incorporated in the making of Nomu.

Answer (score -1):

Endeavor yeeted a fire spear or something at the flying Nomu’s “brain”.However the Nomu has the regeneration quirk and the “brain” would probably regenerate.